# I want to disable the snake being able to go in opposite directions

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

2 questions: I want to disable the snake being able to go in opposite directions (so when it is moving left it cannot go right, if going up cannot go down etc.). How do I do it? Newbie here. Please, as descriptive as possible.

What are all those variables? `px`, `py`, `gs`, `tc`, `ax`, `ay`, `yv`

Here is the full code:

```
<canvas id="gc" width="400" height ="400"></canvas>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    canv=document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
    setInterval(game,1250/15);
}
px=py=10
gs=tc=20;
ax=ay=15;
xv=yv=0;
trail=[];
tail=5;
function game(){
    px+=xv;
    py+=yv;
    if(px<0) {
        px = tc-1;
    }
    if (px>tc-1){
        px = 0;
    }
    if (py<0) {
        py=tc-1;
    }
    if (py>tc-1) {
        py=0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);

    ctx.fillStyle="lime";
    for(var i =0; i<trail.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*gs, trail[i].y*gs, gs-2, gs-2);

        if (trail[i].x==px && trail[i].y ==py) {
            tail =5;
        }
    }

    trail.push({x:px,y:py});
    while(trail.length>tail){
         trail.shift();
    }

    if (ax==px && ay ==py) {
        tail++;
        ax=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
        ay=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
    }

    

    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*gs, ay*gs, gs-2, gs-2);
}



function keyPush(evt){
    switch(evt.keyCode){
        case 37:
            xv=-1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv=0;yv=-1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv=1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv=0;yv=1;
            break;

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Create a var lastMove and store the last move , like up, down, left, top.

Comment: @Grumpy, can you add more details, like where to put and how to implement it?

Comment: function keyPush handles the keys, up, left.down, right, https://keycode.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

px, py, gs, tc, ax, ay, yv are the inital x and y coordinate of snake and the first bullet and the size of the two elements

to disallow move in oposite direction, you can store the previous move inside a variable and allow to move the snake in another direction only if previous move was not the oposite one

```js
window.onload = function() {
  canv = document.getElementById("gc");
  ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
  setInterval(game, 1250 / 15);
}
var previousMove;
px = py = 10
gs = tc = 20;
ax = ay = 15;
xv = yv = 0;
trail = [];
tail = 5;

function game() {
  px += xv;
  py += yv;
  if (px < 0) {
    px = tc - 1;
  }
  if (px > tc - 1) {
    px = 0;
  }
  if (py < 0) {
    py = tc - 1;
  }
  if (py > tc - 1) {
    py = 0;
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  for (var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x * gs, trail[i].y * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);

    if (trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py) {
      tail = 5;
    }
  }

  trail.push({
    x: px,
    y: py
  });
  while (trail.length > tail) {
    trail.shift();
  }

  if (ax == px && ay == py) {
    tail++;
    ax = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
    ay = Math.floor(Math.random() * tc);
  }



  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(ax * gs, ay * gs, gs - 2, gs - 2);
}



function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      if (previousMove !== 39) {
        xv = -1;
        yv = 0;
        previousMove = 37;
      }

      break;
    case 38:
      if (previousMove !== 40) {
        xv = 0;
        yv = -1;
        previousMove = 38;
      }
      break;
    case 39:
      if (previousMove !== 37) {
        xv = 1;
        yv = 0;
        previousMove = 39;
      }
      break;
    case 40:
      if (previousMove !== 38) {
        xv = 0;
        yv = 1;
        previousMove = 40;
      }
      break;

  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

to do it i add a global variable

```
var previousMove;
```

and change the keyPush function to became the following

```
function keyPush(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      if (previousMove !== 39) {
        xv = -1;
        yv = 0;
        previousMove = 37;
      }

      break;
    case 38:
      if (previousMove !== 40) {
        xv = 0;
        yv = -1;
        previousMove = 38;
      }
      break;
    case 39:
      if (previousMove !== 37) {
        xv = 1;
        yv = 0;
        previousMove = 39;
      }
      break;
    case 40:
      if (previousMove !== 38) {
        xv = 0;
        yv = 1;
        previousMove = 40;
      }
      break;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. What is the logic behind these (px, py, gs, tc, ax, ay, yv)? Or do I have to memorize them? Where can I find info about them?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind, can you write which parts of the code you edited?

Comment: i add in the end of my post the two modifications i write to the original code

Comment: for the variable i determine their function by reading code and try play with initial value in the code. If name are not clear for your i can advice to rename it.